# How to build two scenes?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, targets

I have 2 scenes with an ARcamera, image target, and directional light on each scene. The problem happens when I build the APK.

[image]

It only shows scene 0, never the scene set as 1.

I am quite n00b, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that your problem is not one related to building the APK. Given that both scenes are added and selected, they should be built just fine. But Unity will not "play" them one after another.

Scene 0 is set as the first scene. So that will be what it starts with. If you want to switch to a different scene, you'll have to code that.

Unity provides several ways to load a different scene through its [`SceneManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) functionality.

- [`SceneManager.LoadScene(...); //with the scene number or its name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)
- [`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(...); //again, with the scene number or its name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

Both allow for single scene loading or additive loading in addition to the already loaded scenes.

In Unity 5.2 or older this used the now considered obsolete Application methods:

- [`Application.LoadLevel(...); //with the scene number, or its name`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html)
- [`Application.LoadLevelAsync(...); //again, with the scene number or its name`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAsync.html)

or the [two additive scene loading options](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.html), which will leave loaded objects untouched.

So all you need to do is provide some way to make the call to load a different scene, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, now I realise that maybe I didn't understand what "scene" means, I have an AR app and I want to display a 3d model or another (depending on what image target I scan).NOW I have 2 diferent image targets and 2 diferent 3d models I don't want to show both at the same time, only one, what can I do?  Thank you in advance

Comment: A "scene" is basically a game level. If you really want to just display different 3D models, just put them into the exact same scene, but write a script to display or hide them based on the scan. A GameObject will have a SetActive(bool) method. Use this to hide or show the particular model.

Comment: Alternatively I might suggest using `GameObject.renderer.enabled = //true or false`. (assumes the image targets have renderer components)   `SetActive` disables all components and that's not always ideal.